# Can't properly unwrap a simple mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, scale

[image]

UV distortion, apparently some scaling/dimension issue because unwrapping after making the mesh 500 times bigger fixes the problem.

[image]

That's a simple one-sided curved object (7 faces) located perfectly straight (pic. 1). So I expect UVs to be perfectly straight as well. But it gets slightly angled (pic. 2) which is critical for my tiling texture.
Making the mesh much bigger and applying the scale makes the unwrapping process behave right and expected (pic. 3)

Comment: Hi, it's unclear what you are asking. Why do you believe the UVs are distorted? What is your desired result? What do you do to atchieve it? What happens? How is it different from your expectations? Please edit your question using the edit link below it and add this essiantial information.

Comment: Hello! Have done.

Answer (score 0):

[Binary rounding errors](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors) are possible if the values used are very small or very large, or have a lot of significant figures. Blender uses 32bit floats to store values, so it is very possible to observe binary rounding errors in Blender in some cases. However I believe this is more likely because of the unwrapping algorythm used(maybe binary rounding errors are more visible when using it - I am not sure). If you try choosing Conformal instead of Angle Based this will probably solve the issue:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I primarily use the Conformal method. I've tried every option under the unwrap menu with no luck :(

Comment: Could you maybe share the .blend file?

Comment: Sure: https://dropmefiles.com/UCfsc